# Is there a Range Slider in QML?

Tags: qt, slider, qml, qtquick2

I'm looking for an Range-Slider in QML. The goal is to select a range between a maximum and a minimum.

### Example

Lets say I want to create an online shop. Implementing a search for products by price. We have products from 50€ up to 5000€ in stock. A customer only wants to get results for products between 500€ and 1000€. So I need this range slider

```
RangeSlider {
    id: priceSlider
    min: 50
    value1: 500
    value2: 1000
    max: 5000
}
```

Is there an available solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`RangeSlider`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-rangeslider.html#details) was added in Qt 5.6 under the `Qt.labs.controls 1.0` import, and Qt 5.7 under the `QtQuick.Controls 2.0` import. Here's an example from the documentation:

```
RangeSlider {
    from: 1
    to: 100
    first.value: 25
    second.value: 75
}
```

[image: RangeSlider GIF]

---

#### Old answer

No, there's not. It sounds like a useful control to have, though, so I've created a suggestion that it be added to the new Qt Quick Controls:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48667

Comment: Thanks a lot .. even so the answer is not what I hope to read :)

Comment: @Glufu the control has been added and is ready to be used now, if you don't mind cloning Qt yourself and building the 5.6 branch. :)

Answer (score 0):

In qt5.6 and above there is `to` and `from` which equivalent to your `min` and `max`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Qt.labs.controls 1.0
RangeSlider
{
    id:range_slider

    from:min
    to:max
    stepSize: 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of **Qt 5.7**, there is now **QtQuick Controls 2** [which includes `RangeSlider`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-rangeslider.html).

Your code can be implemented as:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 // or higher for newer features

RangeSlider {
    id: priceSlider
    from: 50
    first.value: 500
    second.value: 1000
    to: 5000
}
```